# How to add a new webpage to ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Right now I am making a MVC that has a default page that loads up. From this page, the user can press a button to go to the next page. So far, I have made the first page work and a button that goes to a specified URL for the second page. The only issue I am having is making the view that I want to correspond to the second page have the correct URL.

Here is the code for my button link to the next URL

```
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("IndexA", "HomeController")'" />
```

I guess my question is how do I make my view have the specified URL that I want so it can be accessed?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started) is a good reference for you on getting started using MVC. This is an official Microsoft Documentation on MVC5. Create an `IActionResult` with the Name IndexA in your `HomeController` Like `public IActionResult IndexA()
        {
            return View();
        }`

Comment: I have tried doing that exact IActionResult with all the same code in my HomeController and it still doesn't work. Should my second page view be in the same location as my first view?

Comment: Can you Post your Home Controller code for us to see? Also did you make a .cshtml view in Views>Home named IndexA.cshtml ?

Comment: I figured it out. In the Url.Action, I had to put 'home' instead of 'homecontroller'

Comment: Depends on what that second page will be for.  If, for example, it will display a list of `Widgets` that you sell, then you'd create a new `WidgetController`, with an `Index` method + matching `Index` view that exists in a `Widget` view folder.  I would strongly encourage following the link to the Getting Started page that @akasoggybunz posted, and start from scratch, instead of struggling your way through the learning phase.  You'll be glad that you did.

Comment: @ColinMarks Good Catch I didn't even see that. Yeah MVC assumes that it is a controller so in your `@Url.Action` you can omit controller from the name. So when you make a new controller for example `AdminController.cs` when you call the `Index` it would be `@Url.Action("Index","Admin")`. Congrats on finding the solution. You can go ahead and create your own answer for this question, and accept it as a the solution. For anyone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I used something like this in my own project.

```
    @if (Request.UrlReferrer != null && Request.UrlReferrer.Host == Request.Url.Host)
    {
        <a href="@Request.UrlReferrer" class="dbtn btn-11">
            <i class="fa fa-undo"></i>
            @Resources._Action_Back
        </a>
    }
```

only came from within the domain that was published I said let the button appear.

there is something like add controller in default settings controller name + controller. So just write the name there.

Comment: Could you try different phrases or words for your google translator? Your question is difficult to impossible to understand as it currently is.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this photo.
https://ibb.co/4SS5nYh

You add a new controller and a new view for that new page (also a model). I have called mine Test.

Then in the button. you call them with url action.

```
<input type="button" value="Create" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Test")'" />
```

Comment: I am confused. Could you explain more?

Comment: @ColinMarks please see my edited post. Hope this helps. Also, have a look at https://dotnet.microsoft.com/apps/aspnet/mvc

Answer (score 0):

I had to put "home" in the URL.Action instead of "HomeController"